# Specific Scenario in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I deleted the previous post to make it more clear.

Input XML

```
<Org>
  <Name>OrgName</Name>
  <Type>OrgType</Type>
  <Customer>OrgCust</Customer>
  <Product>
    <ProductData>
      <ID>ID1</ID>
      <Name>Prod1</Name>
      <Grade>Grade1</Grade>
      <Number>13</Number>
    </ProductData>
    <ProductData>
      <ID>ID2</ID>
      <Name>Prod2</Name>
      <Grade>Grade2</Grade>
      <Number>12</Number>
    </ProductData>
  <ProductData>
      <ID>ID3</ID>
      <Name>Prod3</Name>
      <Grade>Grade3</Grade>
      <Number>10</Number>
    </ProductData>
  </Product>
  <Market>TestMarket</Market>
  <Quality>Tested</Quality>
  <Score>70</Score>
</Org>
```

The requirement is to add a node called <Status>Done</Status> to the group Product/ProductData based on the <Number> tag value greater than 10.

If ID3 present in XML and <Number> is greater than 10. The <Status>Done</Status> tag should be added in ID3 only.

If ID3 not valid (<Number> not greater than 10) and ID1 and ID2 both are present in XML and valid (<Number> greater than 10) then add the <Status>Done</Status> tag in ID2.

Else if ID2 and ID3 are not valid (<Number> greater than 10) and ID1 is valid (<Number> greater than 10) then add the <Status>Done</Status> tag to ID1.

Occurrence of ID1, ID2 and ID3 are not fixed.

Below is my XSLT. Here I am finding this difficult to implement the 2nd point which is ID1 and ID2 both valid. I need a global variable and set the value of that variable if one validation match. Then I will check the value of the variable with in loop and skip all other validation. I have tried many ways but not able to figure this out. I went through many posts but no where its mentioned either to use of a flag in for-each or breaking the loop if the condition satisfied. Any guidance on this will be very helpful.

```
<xsl:template match="Org/Product">


  <xsl:for-each select="ProductData">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="ID ='ID1' and Number>10">
        <Status>Done</Status>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="ID ='ID2' and Number>10">
        <Status>Done</Status>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="ID ='ID3' and Number>10">
      <Status>Done</Status>
      </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

The output I am looking for is below

```
<Org>
  <Name>OrgName</Name>
  <Type>OrgType</Type>
  <Customer>OrgCust</Customer>
  <Product>
    <ProductData>
      <ID>ID1</ID>
      <Name>Prod1</Name>
      <Grade>Grade1</Grade>
      <Number>13</Number>
    </ProductData>
    <ProductData>
      <ID>ID2</ID>
      <Name>Prod2</Name>
      <Grade>Grade2</Grade>
      <Number>12</Number>
      <Status>Done</Status>
    </ProductData>
  <ProductData>
      <ID>ID3</ID>
      <Name>Prod3</Name>
      <Grade>Grade3</Grade>
      <Number>10</Number>
    </ProductData>
  </Product>
  <Market>TestMarket</Market>
  <Quality>Tested</Quality>
  <Score>70</Score>
</Org>
```

The version for XSLT is 1.0. Please help.

Comment: The output you show does not match your requirements: the `ProductData` with `ID3` has `<Number>13</Number>` which is greater than 10. Why then is the `<Status>Done</Status>` added to the `ProductData` with `ID2`?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. Fixed it. If ID3 was valid then the Status tag should be added in ID3 only.

Comment: No, your input is the same as it was.

Comment: I manually typed it. Sorry. Fixed now. Please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try perhaps something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="id">
    <xsl:variable name="product" select="/Org/Product/ProductData" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$product[ID='ID3']/Number > 10">ID3</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$product[ID='ID2']/Number > 10">ID2</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$product[ID='ID1']/Number > 10">ID1</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="ProductData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="ID = $id">
            <Status>Done</Status>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If we could be certain of the order in which `ProductData` are listed in the input (or at least if they could be sorted by some property in the wanted order), we could define the `id` variable much more simply - e.g:

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="/Org/Product/ProductData[Number > 10][last()]/ID" />
```

Comment: Got your point. The solution is working. Thank you so much....I was trying with for-each but looks like that is not possible. Template match is the right way. Thank you once again.

Comment: Keep in mind that `xsl:for-each` is not a "loop".